# toObject is not a function error in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the filesPost controllers file. Here I fetch all the datas from MongoDB as well I push datas there. The function works very well without logging in console the **userInfo** but when I try to log it in console, it gives the error that **userInfo.toObject({getters: true})** is not a function. I have tried toJSON() but I got the same error.

```
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const HttpError = require("../models/http-error");
const File = require("../models/file");
const User = require("../models/user");

const getFilesByUserId = async (req, res, next) => {
  const userId = req.params.uid;

  let filePosts;
  try {
    filePosts = await File.find({ creator: userId });
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new HttpError("Fetching failed, please try again.", 500));
  }

  const userInfo = User.findById(userId);

  if (!filePosts || filePosts.length === 0) {
    return next(
      new HttpError("Could not find files for the provided user id.", 404)
    );
  }

  console.log(userInfo.toObject({ getters: true }));
  res.json({
    filePosts: filePosts.map((file) => file.toObject({ getters: true })),
  });
};
```

Comment: Please show us the code of */models/user*. We don't know what `User.findById` does, so we can't tell you why the `userInfo` does not have the method you expect.

Comment: @Bergi this is the user model
`const mongoose = require("mongoose");`
`const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");`

`const Schema = mongoose.Schema;`
`const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true, minlength: 5 },
  image: { type: String, required: true },
  files: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: "File" }],
});`

`userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);`
`module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your async function, your code continues even though the call to `User.findById(userId)` isn't complete. You can use an `await` statement to ensure that the function has run before your code continues.

Your code should work if you change `const userInfo = User.findById(userId);` to

```js
const userInfo = await User.findById(userId);
```

For more information, here is the async/await documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: That's true I just figured that out! Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add await.

`const userInfo = await User.findById(userId);`